# Solving Abstract Problems

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, problem-solving

[image]

I'm doing this Solving Abstract Problem but I'm not sure which one it is. I mean from the Series I can see there's a pattern but in the Options I don't see images that link with the Series. Do you have any idea - unless it's B but it's note very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is E.

At each step in the series, X goes round 45 degrees counterclockwise while the circle goes round 45 degrees clockwise.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine there are two pendulums, one with an X end and the other with a circle. They are spinning in different "directions". So the answer should be E.

Cheers!